# Serialize class from ToString method

Tags: c#

I am using JSon.Net to serialize a ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel {
   public Int32 Id { get; set; }
   // other properties
}

public static class ViewModelExtensions {

  public static IHtmlString ToJson(this ViewModel model) {

    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
      ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, settings));

  } // ToJson

} // ViewModelExtensions
```

Instead of using an extension model could I use add a method ToString in ViewModel class to serialize the class itself?

How can I do this? And what is the best option?

Comment: And basically replace model by this, right?

Answer (score 2):

The default ToString is a virtual function so you should be able to override it by just doing this:

```
override public string ToString() {
    return [Your format logic here];
}
```

I think that is what you are going for.

Comment: I'd strongly advice against overriding ToString(), as the Framework calls that method in a number of places; it would be better to create a new method such as ToJsonString()

Comment: Out of curiosity do you know what instances the framework would do this in? In seems odd to me that they would expose it to being overridden and then rely on its unaltered functionality. Not that I don't believe you, I am just interested to see why they would do it.

Comment: The Framework doesn't "rely" on it to be unaltered, but it does use it... basically, any time it wants to "print" an object it just calls .ToString. that could include logging, exception messages, data binding, etc. Places you may not want your object's internals to be user-visible.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended with the following based on the comments I received:

```
public class ViewModel {

  public IHtmlString ToJson() {
    return ToJson(new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
  } // ToJson

  public IHtmlString ToJson(IContractResolver resolver) {
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
      ContractResolver = resolver 
    };
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, settings));

  } // ToJson

} // ViewModel
```